# Ionic - Trouble with Deleting Items in an Array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

I'm following a guide that shows how to build a to-do list app in ionic. The guide doesn't show how to remove items from the list, so I decided to try it myself. I can't for the life of me get my `removeItem()` function to work. No matter which item in the list I tap the delete button on, it deletes the last item in the list. I'll include the page and template that involve the `removeItem()` function. Anyone have any ideas or tips?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AddItemPage } from '../add-item/add-item'
import { ItemDetailPage } from '../item-detail/item-detail';
import { Data } from '../../providers/data/data';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
 
  public items = [];
 
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public dataService: Data) {
 
    this.dataService.getData().then((todos) => {
 
      if(todos){
        this.items = JSON.parse(todos); 
      }
 
    });
 
  }
 
  ionViewDidLoad(){
 
  }
 
  addItem(){
 
    let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddItemPage);
 
    addModal.onDidDismiss((item) => {
 
          if(item){
            this.saveItem(item);
          }
 
    });
 
    addModal.present();
 
  }
 
  saveItem(item){
    this.items.push(item);
    this.dataService.save(this.items);
  }

removeItem(item) {  
  //this.items.splice(item, 1);
  let index = this.items.indexOf(item);
  this.items.splice(index,  1);

  this.dataService.save(this.items);
}
 

  viewItem(item){
    this.navCtrl.push(ItemDetailPage, {
      item: item
    });
  }
 
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color = "secondary">
    <ion-title>
      To-do List
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addItem()"><ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" >{{item.title}}
        <ion-buttons end> 
            <button ion-button icon-only color="danger" (click)="removeItem()"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
          </ion-buttons>
    </ion-item> 
    
    

    
    
   
    

  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to know, which item to remove, so you can pass it as argument:

```
(click)="removeItem(item)"
```

It will get current item from `*ngFor` loop and will pass as an argument.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Devinm not at all, you was so close =)